# UnitTest Method for AJAX JSON Calls to an API

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to write test cases for our AJAX calls to our API. Doing a simply web request and response. My question is with regard to the response. Is there a simpler way to pull out the response JSON values?  Is the best way to do this sort of thing? I know we could us JQuery, but wanted to use Microsoft Testing framework.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string brand = "KEWL";
        string BRAND = "";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://203.135.xx.138:4040/api/v1/subscriptions/signup.format");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = @"{" +
           " 'api_key': '91230D10-247C-11E1-83FF-9B9C4824019B'," +
           " 'phone': '12122639043', " +
           " 'dob': '11231954', " +
           "      'subscriptions': [ " +
           "                {" +
           "                 'Brand':'" + brand + "', " +
           "                'campaign':'BTLNDN', " +
           "                    'groups':[" +
           "                            {" +
           "                            'group': 'BTLALL'," +
           "                            'subscribed':true" +
           "                            } " +
           "                    ]," +
           "   'lang': 'en' " +
           "                }" +
           "                ] " +
           "   }";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> dc = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(responseText);
            var kev = dc;
            foreach (var key1 in dc.Keys)
            {
               var value3 = dc["ReturnData"]["subscriptions"];
                 BRAND = value3[0]["brand"];
             //   var groups = value3[0]["groups"];
            }


        }
        Assert.AreEqual(brand, BRAND);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, HTTP request in a unit test. Unit tests are not supposed to do such things. This looks more like an integration test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of unit testing ASP.NET MVC methods is that you can run the test without using any Http request or respond functionality.

Suppose you have the following method:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAjax()
    {
        return Json(new { Test = "Test" });
    }
}
```

You can test it with this code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    MyControllercontroller = new MyController();

    JsonResult json = controller.MyAjax() as JsonResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(json);

    dynamic data = json.Data;

    Assert.AreEqual("Test", data.Test);
}
```

To use the dynamic keyword you have to make sure that your test project can see the internals of your web project (this is because anonymous types are declared internal). You can do this by adding: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestProject")]` to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of your web project.

Comment: Thanks – This is a great way to test, but what if these were our external API’s that we were letting people access externally. Would this test method make sense? test routing, external access etc. Would there ever be a reason to test this way?

Comment: @BillPorter If you are Unit Testing, this is the way to go. A lot of Unit tests will confirm that your code is behaving as expected. You will then only need some functional tests to make sure that everything is working together as you expected. If this is your external API, you still want to make sure that your function is behaving as expected(Unit test).